# Cakephp 2.5 search box not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am a beginner in CakePHP. I want to do a simple search box, but it is not working, below is the code in my controller:-

```
public function index() {         
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->loadModel('Job');
        $this->request->data = $keyword; 
        $result = $this->Job->find('all', array(
            'condition'=>array('Job.title'=>'% $keyword %')
        ));
        $this->set('rslt',$result); 
        //$this->set('kc',$keyword);
    } 
}
```

For my view, I have the code below:-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('search', array('type'=>'get'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('search');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit');?>    

<pre><?php print_r($rslt) ; ?></pre>
```

However the search result displays a blank page.

Comment: What is `$this->request->data = $keyword;` for? You shouldn't be altering `$this->request->data` like this really. Where are you getting `$keyword` from?

Comment: $keyword is the variable that is coming from the search form

Answer (score 1):

There look to be a few issues with your code.

Firstly, you should be getting your keyword from the request data, *e.g.* `$this->request->data['search']['keyword']`. Don't overwrite `$this->request->data` like in your example code; it is meant to be an array of data submitted to the page, you're replacing this with a string!

Secondly, your condition needs to look something like `'Job.title LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data['search']['keyword'] . '%'`. Using single quotes around a PHP variable treats it as a string so will not replace it with the variable's value. Instead we only quote the `%`s.

You were also missing the `LIKE` keyword for the search in the condition index.

The code in your controller should look something like:-

```
public function index() {         
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->loadModel('Job');
        $result = $this->Job->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Job.title LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data['search']['keyword'] . '%')
        ));
        $this->set('rslt',$result); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to do any editing on my view file? I mean where I have the form

Comment: Instead of this error prone approach you should better use the search plugin https://github.com/CakeDC/search and a proper PRG approach. That will resolve all issues at once, and cleanly.

Comment: I think I am making headway now, It is showing some result, but the result are not related to the searched keyword, it is displaying everything in the database

Comment: @user2090999 slightly modified my answer so that it is no longer dependent on the form submission type. What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: How do I see the sql generated? i have removed it

Comment: @user2090999 install DebugKit (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) if you haven't already. It will give you a panel of all the queries run for the page (make sure you enable debug in 'Config/core.php').

Comment: I assume there are no cake experts on stackoverflow, please advice me where can i get a solution?

Comment: @user2090999 have you tried checking the SQL Cake is generating? The query shown in my answer should be working, but perhaps your app is doing something else to alter the `find`. If you can show us the query being generated perhaps we can identify if there is another problem.

Comment: You will probably be better off installing the Cake search plugin that mark suggested rather than battle with your existing code if you are making no progress.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I have serious doubts he will get the plugin to work from what I've seen here...

Comment: @drmonkeyninja below is the sql that is being generated array(
 'log' => array(
  (int) 0 => array(
   'query' => 'SELECT `Job`.`id`, `Job`.`title`, `Job`.`description`, `Job`.`location`, `Job`.`companyname`, `Job`.`jobtype`, `Job`.`industry`, `Job`.`salary`, `Job`.`contactname`, `Job`.`closingdate`, `Job`.`poster`, `Job`.`created`, `Job`.`modified` FROM `cakephp`.`jobs` AS `Job`   WHERE 1 = 1',
   'params' => array(),
   'affected' => (int) 9,
   'numRows' => (int) 9,
   'took' => (float) 2

Comment: I think this is where I am having problems now...@drmonkeyninja    $result = $this->Job->find('all', array(
                   'condition'=>array('Job.title'=> $keyword)
                 ));

Comment: THanks all, I have fixed it @drmonkeyninja i didnt add "s" to the word "conditions", it is supposed to be "conditions" but i typed "condition"  thanks

Comment: @user2090999 just noticed a typo in my answer. `condition` should be `conditions` (plural). Just fixed it. Try correcting that as it looks wrong in your question too! If you only want exact matches use `'conditions'=>array('Job.title'=>$keyword)` otherwise for titles containing the keyword use `'conditions'=>array('Job.title LIKE'=>'%'.$keyword.'%')`.

Answer (score 0):

You form method is set to `"GET"` not post as you are trying to access it in your controller.

//Your view code

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('search', array('type'=>'get'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('search');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit');?>
```

You should do this in your controller.

```
if($this->request->is('get')){
  $keyword = $this->request->data['search'];
// OR $keyword = $_GET['search'];

$this->Job->find('all', array('conditions' => 
  'Job.colunmName LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'
))
}
```

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, the page started showing blank

Comment: Try if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])){
  $this->Job->find('all', array('conditions' => 
  'Job.colunmName LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'
))
}

Remember to pass value back to your view with $this->set(), also replace colunmName with your table colunm and Job with your Model name

Comment: I a tired., now the text box in my view is showing like a select box

Comment: To make things easier, you can just create normal HTML form. Not CakePHP helper generated. And see if that works fine first.

<form method="get" action="yourControllerMethod"> <input type="text" name="search"> <button type="submit"> </form> and run it with that previous controller method.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
'% $keyword %'
```

to this:

```
'%$keyword%'
```

That is, remove the spaces, else the generated SQL will try to find the keyword surrounded by spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, but still blank page that shows

Comment: Also, in your view, change `array('type'=>'get')` to `array('type'=>'post')`, else your data will be sent via 'get' method while your code only accepts data fro; the 'post' method.

Comment: I think I am making headway now, It is showing some result, but the result are not related to the searched keyword, it is displaying everything in the database

Comment: Just wondering, did you fix the variable assignment? 
It should be = `$keyword = $this->request->data;` rather than
`$this->request->data = $keyword;`

Comment: I just did that, but it is still showing all the records in the database

Comment: single quotes still won't interpolate the variable